Apply network graph to custom views in Android Studio
I'm creating an app in Android Studio. The goal of the app is to make the user see which relationships he has with other users who also use the app. A network graph, so to speak. I also created custom views, as I'd like to have more control over what elements get displayed in this graph.
However, I don't know a suitable way to create a network graph, because in my scenario I'd need to compute a network graph for my Fragment and then apply the computed coordinates to my custom views in order to create the correct network graph with my views.
Can anybody give me a heads up how I would do this?

You need to describe what you're trying to accomplish in more detail, it's not exactly clear.  A picture may be the easiest way

I need a way to calculate the positions of nodes and edges in a network graph. The graph should be calculated via an algorithm, like the Fruchterman-Reingold algorithm. After the algorithm has calculated the layout of the network graph, instead of displaying the graph like you normally would, I'd only need the coordinates of each calculated node and edge. I would then use these coordinates to apply them to my custom views, creating a new network graph with my own views which has the layout of the calculated network graph that used the algorithm.

Sounds like you need to create a custom layout if using views.  The custom Layout would display the nodes at the calculated positions.  If using compose.... I have no idea how you'd do it.

Thanks for your answer! A question, is my approach too complex? I'm stuck at getting the coordinates for my custom views, as I don't know how to get specific coordinates from any of the libraries which provide the algorithm.

What do you get from the libraries?
